# Query update fails to update number

Tags: php, mysql

I found out that I should use floor and rand when I want to update a column with a random number from 1 to 3. Found it on another question on this site. 
However, it does not seem to work for me all though I followed the instructions given in the other post.

I've been troubleshooting for the past hour and a half and I badly need help.
my code is:

```
$result = $mysqli->query('UPDATE users_extended SET field3 = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 ');
```

Do you know where my fail is?

Thank you on behalf

Comment: What exactly fails? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close Parentheses

```
$result = $mysqli->query('UPDATE users_extended SET field3 = FLOOR( 1 + RAND( ) *3 )');
```

Comment: Jesus christ I hate php sometimes..... but yes, you are right. thanks a lot bro haha

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed a closing parenthesis before the apostrophe.

Try

```
$result = $mysqli->query('UPDATE users_extended SET field3 = FLOOR( 1 + RAND() * 3)');
```